# Adding Custom Data fields to an excel Pivot Table Using EPPlus

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

I have created a Pivot Table on a worksheet using EPPlus and want to add a custom data field programatically. How would one go about doing this?

My pivot table consists of:

Columns : Years,

Rows : Companies,

Data : currently a sum of the revenues for each year

I would like to add a column which gives the revenue for each company as 'Year to date' i.e. the last 12 months from the current point in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I added an additional field which flagged whether that particular bit of data had been created since the beginning of the same year. I then Filtered on this flag.